# My MS access update one row

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

My MS access update one row, but after trying to update another value,
its working but the last value is removed what seems to be the problem?
thank you to all those that help.

```
protected void Btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem RI in rptEdit.Items)
        {
            Label Pid = RI.FindControl("Pid") as Label;
            TextBox prdname = RI.FindControl("prdname") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdprice = RI.FindControl("prdprice") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdshortdesc = RI.FindControl("prdshortdesc") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdtype = RI.FindControl("prdtype") as TextBox;
            TextBox prdbrand = RI.FindControl("prdbrand") as TextBox;
            Literal ltl = RI.FindControl("ltlmsg") as Literal;
            string myid = Pid.Text;

            string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Table.accdb";
            string SqlString = "UPDATE ProductList SET Pname = '" + prdname.Text + "' WHERE Pid = ? ";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = myid;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pname", prdname.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ltl.Text = "<br/>Done.";
                    conn.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem RI in rptEdit.Items)
        {
            Literal ltl = RI.FindControl("ltlmsg") as Literal;
            ltl.Text = "Error messegae: <br/>" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're confusing `udpate` with `insert`. Update changes an existing record; `insert` adds a new one. If you need to insert, you need a whole new query and 'procedure'. Edit...actually I'm not sure if I understood what you're asking. What do you mean 'another value'?

Comment: This is the 3rd time I've seen you ask about this. Just wondering why all those controls are referenced inside the foreach; they're never used (mostly).

Comment: Hello,
I am able to update my database.
I click the edit button, edit and confirm.
But after trying to update another cell in my database through the table.
The previous cell I had updated had been erased.

Comment: and i dont use all the controls because i want to sucsess firts just with one value.

Comment: Do you mean "value" for the Update clause? Or are you reffering "value" to a row or recordset? As what I can see, you're only providing one update value: `pName`.

Comment: i mean to record.
because i sucsess to update just one record,
if im trying to edit another time other cell in my table,
the last record are delete.